# Why I get only one row printed from my sql?

Tags: php, sql, loops, printing

There is two rows that should be printed from my sql.

id    Symbol    Shares
3     CSCO      40
3     FB        200

but this code prints only first row twice. Like this:
jharvard has 40 shares of CSCOjharvard has 40 shares of CSCO

Why?

Thanky you in an advance.

```
$users = query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?", $_SESSION["id"]);   
$rows = query("SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE id = ?", $_SESSION["id"]);

$stock = $rows[0];
$username = $users[0];

foreach ($rows as $row)
{
if( $stock["id"] === $_SESSION["id"])
{
print("<td>" . $username["username"] . "   has   "  . $stock["Shares"] .   "   shares of   "   . $stock["Symbol"] . "</td>");
}
}
```

Comment: what does the `query()` function return?

Comment: Because in your loop you `print` from `$stock`, which you set to the **first record** of `$rows`.  But, your loop is looping over `$rows`, so I suspect you mean to `print` the `$row["Shares"]` instead of the `$stock["Shares"];

Comment: If the answer below solved your issue, it is good form to accept the answer...

Answer (score 1):

The reason is your variables inside the loop

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    if( $stock["id"] === $_SESSION["id"]) {
        print("<td>" . $username["username"] . "   has   "  . $stock["Shares"] .   "   shares of   "   . $stock["Symbol"] . "</td>");
    }
}
```

You are printing the value of `$stock`, which earlier you defined:

```
$stock = $row[0];
```

So it will **always** output the data from the first row.

I suspect you want to change your loop as follows:

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    // Changed from $stock['id'] to $row['id']
    if( $row["id"] === $_SESSION["id"]) {
        // Changed from $stock['Shares'] and ['Symbol'] to $row['Shares'] and ['Symbol']
        print("<td>" . $username["username"] . "   has   "  . $row["Shares"] .   "   shares of   "   . $row["Symbol"] . "</td>");
    }
}
```